# How do we display highlighted option between the required option from the react-select menu options not the first option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-select

I am using react-select for the list of years in DOB. And my requirement is:- **When I click on the select input, I need to highlight the list with 2000 by default before selecting anything.** But currently, it's always highlighting the first option of the list.

The constructor of the class looks like:-

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let val ;
    if(this.props.value){
          val=this.props.value;
    }
    // console.log(val);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
    this.state={
      selectedOption:val,
      hidden:true,
      isError:false,
      error:"",
      cursor: 0,
    }
 }
```

this.props.value is either placeholder if not selected or selected value from its parent component. And this.state.selectedOption changes with change of value.

My select props looks like:-

```
    <Select
          value={this.defaultValue}
          onChange={(value)=>this.selectItem(value)}
          name={this.props.name}
          options={countryNames}
          defaultValue={{value:this.state.selectedOption,label:this.state.selectedOption}}
          styles={customSelectStyles}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          isSearchable={true}
          theme={(theme) => ({
            ...theme,
            borderRadius: 0,
            colors: {
              ...theme.colors,
              primary: '#235d9a',
            },
            fontFamily: 'Ubuntu',
            fontWeight: '300',

            height: {
              ...theme.height,
              primary: '48px',
            },
          })}

          menuContainerStyle={{'zIndex': 999}}
    />
```

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Please show definition of selectItem function and where do you set this.state.selectedOption?

Comment: Hi Khusbu! I have given a little bit more details now. Let me know if you need more clarification. Thanks